# How to avoid the NULL output of str()

Tags: r, string, function

I realized that `str()` returns a `NULL` to the assigned object (if assigned) and reading a bit I noticed that this is because `str()` uses the `invisible()` function under the hood. Is there any argument on `str()` that disable that so it can actually return the structure of the object?

Comment: Do you just want the text that you get with `capture.output`?  Or do you want something else?

Comment: Part of your question is just wrong. The use of `invisible` does not prevent the return of a value. It is rather that fact that invisible gets no argument that allows `str.default` to return NULL. Many functions return their non-NULL values by passing them through invisible.

Comment: This seems like an xy problem. Why do you want to store the output of `str` in a variable? In 8 years of using R I never needed that (and I have answered a few "interesting" questions on Stack Overflow). There is probably a much better approach to your actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str()` is called for its side effect of printing to the console, not for its return value. That said, if you want to capture that text and store it in an object rather than having it printed to the console, you can do so using the function `capture.output()`. Here's an example:

```
x <- capture.output(str(mtcars))

x[1:4]
#  [1] "'data.frame':\t32 obs. of  11 variables:"                          
#  [2] " $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ..."  
#  [3] " $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ..."                            
#  [4] " $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ..."                            

cat(x[1:4], sep="\n")
# 'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
#  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
```